# Elegant way to convert epoch timestamp to Eastern Time and reverse using Nodatime

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, portable-class-library, nodatime

I am working on [writing a managed wrapper around Massachusetts Bay Transportation Authority (MBTA) Realtime API](https://github.com/manish/mbta-sharp). They have a API which returns the server time which is unix timestamp (epoch). The library under which I am implementing it is PCL `Profile 78` which means I have limited support for BCL TimeZone, so I resorted to using `Nodatime`

I am trying to convert the time returned from server to Eastern Time which is `America/New_York` as a `DateTime` object and reverse way. [My current code is very dirty](https://github.com/manish/mbta-sharp/blob/master/Cassini.MBTA/TimeUtils.cs)

```
public static class TimeUtils
{
    static readonly DateTimeZone mbtaTimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
    static readonly DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    public static DateTime GetMbtaDateTime (long unixTimestamp)
    {
        var mbtaEpochTime = epoch.AddSeconds (unixTimestamp);
        var instant = Instant.FromUtc (mbtaEpochTime.Year, mbtaEpochTime.Month,
            mbtaEpochTime.Day, mbtaEpochTime.Hour, mbtaEpochTime.Minute, mbtaEpochTime.Second);
        var nodaTime = instant.InZone (mbtaTimeZone);
        return nodaTime.ToDateTimeUnspecified ();
    }

    public static long MbtaDateTimeToUnixTimestamp (DateTime time)
    {
        TimeSpan secondsSinceEpochMbtaTz = time - epoch;
        var instant = Instant.FromUtc (time.Year, time.Month, time.Day, time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second);
        var mbtaTzSpan = mbtaTimeZone.GetUtcOffset (instant).ToTimeSpan ();
        var epochDiff = secondsSinceEpochMbtaTz - mbtaTzSpan;
        return (long)epochDiff.TotalSeconds;
    }
}
```

Is there another way to write this simply. I hope Nodatime should have support for converting an epoch time to `America/New_York` DateTime and `America/New_York` DateTime to epoch time. My method `MbtaDateTimeToUnixTimestamp` is a brutal hack

Comment: Do you really need to use `DateTime` at all? Noda Time works best when you use it throughout your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, as mentioned in comments, it would be best to use Noda Time types throughout your code - only resort to `DateTime` when you *really* have to. This should lead to significantly cleaner code throughout.

Converting a Unix timestamp to an `Instant` is really easy:

```
Instant instant = Instant.FromUnixTimeSeconds(seconds);
```

You can then convert into a `ZonedDateTime` as per your current code... and using `ToDateTimeUnspecified` is fine if you really need to use `DateTime`.

For the reverse, your current code looks broken to me - you're assuming the `DateTime` is a UTC value, effectively. That would be at odds with your later use of the time zone. I suspect you want to convert the input to a `LocalDateTime`, and then apply the time zone. For example:

```
public static long MbtaDateTimeToUnixTimestamp(DateTime time)
{
    var local = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(time);
    var zoned = local.InZoneStrictly(mbtaTimeZone);
    var instant = zoned.ToInstant();
    return instant.Ticks / NodaConstants.TicksPerSecond;
}
```

Note the `InZoneStrictly` call. This will throw an exception if either you pass in a local time which didn't exist *or* one that existed twice - in both cases due to DST transitions. This may well *not* be what you want - you really need to think about what you want to happen in those cases, or try to avoid them being feasible. See the [time zones section of the documentation](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/concepts.html#time-zones) for more details and options.

Comment: The `FromSecondsSinceUnixEpoch` is not defined anymore in `Instance`. EDIT: It contains now a `FromUnixTimeSeconds`.